# No matching call to connect - when I set 7 parameters. works fine with 6 parameters

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread

Is there a restriction on number of parameters of signals?

```
/home/.../testerslow/jjjj.h:36: error: no matching function for call to 'Controller::connect(Controller* const, void (Controller::*)(int, int, int, int, int, int, int), Worker*&, void (Worker::*)(int, int, int, int, int, int, int))'
         connect (this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
```

In the following code, just reduce 1 parameter to the signal slot dowork and operate and the error will vanish.

What's the way to pass 7th argument?

**Reproducable example:**

```
#ifndef JJJJ
#define JJJJ
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>


class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker() { }

public slots:
    void doWork (int one, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int h)
    {
        emit resultReady("");
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QThread workerThread;

public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;

        connect (&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect (this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect (worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

        workerThread.start();
    }

    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }

public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &) {}

signals:
    void operate(int, int, int,int,int,int, int);
};
#endif // JJJJ
```

Comment: From [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments): "Note that if your compiler does not support C++11 variadic templates, this syntax only works if the signal and slot have 6 arguments or less." You could instead use the SIGNAL and SLOT macros, which internally create strings.

Comment: Put these variables in a struct or a class and pass that instead.

Comment: @KarstenKoop much thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments), you are limited to calls with six arguments or less using new-style syntax unless your compiler supports variadic template signatures. A quick solution is to create a container type and register it with [`QMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html) using [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) and [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1).

First, declare the data type:

```
//foo.h
#include <QMetaType>

struct Foo 
{
    int one, b, c, d, e, f, h;
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)
```

Since you're using threads, which means queued signals, you also need to register the metatype at runtime with `qRegisterMetaType`, usually in `main` or some initialization function that is only called once:

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaType>
#include "foo.h"

int main(...)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<Foo>();
    ... //do more things here
    return app.exec()
}
```

You should now be able to use `Foo` in signal and slot connections without issue using the following for your signal and slot signatures:

```
void doWork(Foo foo);
```

and

```
void operate(Foo);
```

Comment: P.S. Kudos on properly using QThread instead of subclassing. I don't think that anti-pattern will ever go away.